# wrong file path when uploading a file in django

Tags: python, django, django-file-upload

I have a following model for my files:

```
class Import(models.Model):
     file = models.FileField(upload_to='%Y/%m/%d')
```

And I save them like this:

```
f = request.FILES['import']
if f.size < settings.MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE:
    x = Import.objects.create(file=f)
```

My media root:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join('/home/xyz/project/main', 'upload/')
```

The problem is, when I inspect my x object like:

```
print x.file.path
```

it will return "/home/my-computer-name/..." instead of "/home/xyz/...".
What am I doing wrong? Django 1.8, Ubuntu.
The file has been uploaded to correct path.

Comment: You are on windows or Linux?

Comment: I'm on Linux, ubuntu.

Comment: main is the name of my project. it contains manage.py

Comment: have you tried the way I told you? Is that working fine for your Project?

Answer (score 1):

ok, forget it. I just put wrong settings file when printing the path